# DataTemplateSelector and Windows 8

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, windows-8, datatemplateselector

I have very strange problem.
I have written application using wpf, telerik(office2007 theme).
I use DataTemplateSelector to dynamicly create view for different types of models.
In windows 7 all fine and good works, but in windows 8 DataTemplateSelector not work!
WTF?
Can You help me with my problem?

```
public class TabDataTemplateSelector:DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        if(item==null || container == null)
            return null;
        FrameworkElement element = Application.Current.MainWindow as FrameworkElement;
        if (element == null)
            return null;
        if (item is PetrochemicalCatalogViewModel)
        {
            return element.FindResource("PetrochemicalCatalogDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if (item is FuelPriceViewModel)
        {
            return element.FindResource("FuelPriceDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if (item is RoleViewModel)
        {
            return element.FindResource("RoleDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if (item is IEquipmentViewModel)
        {
            return element.FindResource("EquipmentDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if (item is IZondsViewModel)
        {
            return element.FindResource("ZondDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if (item is ITankCatalogViewModel)
        {
            return element.FindResource("TanksDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if (item is IDispensersWorkplaceViewModel)
        {
            return element.FindResource("DispensingDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if (item is IDispenserSetsWorkplaceViewModel)
        {
            return element.FindResource("DispenserSetsWorkplaceTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if (item is IPaymentTypeCatalogViewModel)
        {
            return element.FindResource("PaymentTypeWorkplaceTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if (item is ICashManagementViewModel)
        {
            return element.FindResource("CashManagementTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if (item is ITerminalWorkplaceViewModel)
        {
            return element.FindResource("TerminalDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        if (item is IPriceingWorkplaceViewModel)
        {
            return element.FindResource("PriceingDataTemplate") as DataTemplate;
        }
        return null;
    }
}

<local:TabDataTemplateSelector x:Key="tabDataTemplateSelector"/>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="TabContentTemplate">
            <telerik:RadBusyIndicator x:Name="rbiBusy" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsBusy="{Binding IsBusy}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" telerik:StyleManager.Theme="Windows8Touch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch">
                    <ContentPresenter  ContentTemplateSelector="{StaticResource tabDataTemplateSelector}"  Content="{Binding TabContentViewModel}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"/>                    
            </telerik:RadBusyIndicator>               
        </DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Perhaps if you had [asked a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) according to [the way that we do things here on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help), you would have got some answers by now.

Comment: Is anybody know about this problem?

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to improve your question.

Answer (score 3):

Things are a little different from windows 7 and windows 8.
I had the same issue and what i discovered is that the DataType property is not support for DataTemplate in windows 8, so i had to select it based on their name and use a custom DataTemplateSelector.
Here's and extract of my code where a list is filled with different types:

XAML:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <s:CustomDataTemplateSelector
        x:Key="CustomDataTemplateSelector" />
    <DataTemplate
        x:Key="Activity1">
        <c:ActivityControl1 />
    </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate
        x:Key="Activity2">
        <c:ActivityControl2 />
  </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ListView
        FontSize="20"
        BorderThickness="0"
        Foreground="Black"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Activities}"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CustomDataTemplateSelector}" />
</Grid>
```

CS:

```
public class CustomDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    protected override DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        string key = item.GetType().Name;
        FrameworkElement element = container as FrameworkElement;
        while (element != null)
        {
            if (element.Resources.ContainsKey(key))
                return element.Resources[key] as DataTemplate;
            element = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(element) as FrameworkElement;
        }
        return Application.Current.Resources[key] as DataTemplate;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to do what you want would be to put each of your `DataTemplate`s into a `UserControl` (without the `DataTemplate` object, eg. just add the contents), name them `...View` (where '...' comes from the related view model class) and connect them to your view models using `DataTemplate`s defined in `App.xaml`:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:PetrochemicalCatalogViewModel}">
    <Views:PetrochemicalCatalogView />
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:FuelPriceViewModel}">
    <Views:FuelPriceView />
</DataTemplate>
...
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:IPriceingWorkplaceViewModel}">
    <Views:IPriceingWorkplaceView />
</DataTemplate>
```